# Wordpress woocommerc search result

Tags: wordpress, search, woocommerce

Why the search result giving the ID of product not name?

I made taxonomy for witters in Woocommerce, and want to filter all witers and display books from selected writter.

This is taxonomy:

```
<pre>if (!function_exists('bookcover_books_taxonomy')) {
    function bookcover_books_taxonomy() {

        // Writters
        $labels = array(
            'name'                       => _x( 'Writters', 'taxonomy general name' ),
            'singular_name'              => _x( 'Writter', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
            'search_items'               => __( 'Search writters' ),
            'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular writters' ),
            'all_items'                  => __( 'All writters' ),
            'parent_item'                => null,
            'parent_item_colon'          => null,
            'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit writter' ),
            'update_item'                => __( 'Update writter' ),
            'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add new writter' ),
            'new_item_name'              => __( 'New writter name' ),
            'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate writters with commas' ),
            'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove writter' ),
            'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used writter' ),
            'not_found'                  => __( 'No writter found.' ),
            'menu_name'                  => __( 'Writters' )
        );
        $args = array(
            'labels'                     => $labels,
            'hierarchical'               => true,
            'public'                     => true,
            'show_ui'                    => true,
            'show_admin_column'          => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
            'show_tagcloud'              => true,
            'rewrite'                    => array('slug' => 'writter')
        );
        register_taxonomy( 'writter', 'product', $args );


    }
    add_action('init', 'bookcover_books_taxonomy', 0);
}</pre>
```

And this is search form:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>">
<label class="screen-reader-text" for="s"><?php _e('Search for books', 'woocommerce'); ?></label>

<?php
wp_dropdown_categories(array(
    'show_option_all'    => 'all categories',
    'show_option_none'   => '',
    'orderby'            => 'name', 
    'order'              => 'ASC',
    'show_count'         => 1,
    'hide_empty'         => 1, 
    'child_of'           => 0,
    'exclude'            => '',
    'echo'               => 1,
    'selected'           => 0,
    'hierarchical'       => 0, 
    'name'               => 'writter',
    'id'                 => '',
    'class'              => 'postform',
    'depth'              => 0,
    'tab_index'          => 0,
    'taxonomy'           => 'writter',
    'hide_if_empty'      => false,
    'walker'             => ''
    ));
?>
<?php wp_list_categories() ?>
<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="&#xf002;" />
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" />
```

When you select one writer from drop down list, and press search, you get this url
`/?writter=27&post_type=product`

The problem is in thisnumber 27, I need to display name of writer, for example
`/?writter=john-doe&post_type=product`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think this code might be help to you.

```
<form role="search" action="<?php echo site_url('/'); ?>" method="get" id="searchform">
 <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s"><?php _e('Search for books', 'woocommerce'); ?></label>

<?php
     wp_dropdown_categories(array(
'show_option_all'    => 'all categories',
'show_option_none'   => '',
'orderby'            => 'name', 
'order'              => 'ASC',
'show_count'         => 1,
'hide_empty'         => 1, 
'child_of'           => 0,
'exclude'            => '',
'echo'               => 1,
'selected'           => 0,
'hierarchical'       => 0, 
'name'               => 'writter',
'id'                 => '',
'class'              => 'postform',
'depth'              => 0,
'tab_index'          => 0,
'taxonomy'           => 'writter',
'hide_if_empty'      => false,
'walker'             => ''
));
wp_list_categories() ?>
<input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search Products"/>
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" /> <!-- // hidden 'products' value -->
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $term->name; ?>" name="catname" />
<input type="submit" alt="Search" value="Search" />
</form>
```